# Pay by cash magento backend

Tags: magento, payment, magento-1.9, payment-method

Hi guys i have problem,

Sometimes we go to events and there we sell our products. I want to add this transactions into magento store. When i create new order i can add everything with out payment method. I try to add

```
protected $_canUseCheckout = false;
protected $_canUseForMultishipping = false;
```

to Checkmo.php file and

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
protected $_canUseCheckout = false;
```

into Purchaseorder.php file

It still doesn't work, how should i do now? I want to add pay in cash method or something like this. Thanks for help

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why do you need to change your code? This can be done in magento backend by default.

Comment: When i create new order i can't select any payment option - "no avaiable payment option"

Answer (score 0):

In System > Config > SALES > Payment Methods activate `Check / Money order`.

(You might want to deactivate it afterwards if you don't want to appear on frontend. Or just hide it.)